# How to remove large amount of white space in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's so much extra space in the terminal. What should I do to remove those spaces?

[image: integrated terminal with large amount of white space]

Comment: use `Help > Dev Tools` to inspect what is there between the first prompt and the python command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write "cls" and press enter

Hope this helps:-)